# pass value from Android to JSP

Tags: android, jsp, post, parameters

I am just new to the Android development.
Currently, I am doing register function in android client.
What I want to do now is just to pass the username and password into the JSP page. But when I tried on my app, it seems not passing the value into the `JSP`.

**Android:**

```
    public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    String url = "http://101.78.175.101:20281/test/useradd.jsp";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.registeractivity);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

            List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", "hardik"));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pwd", "trivedi"));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
            client.execute(post);

            TextView mail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Register_mail);
            mail.setText("hello");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**JSP code:**

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<%
String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxx";
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
int insert_flag = 0 ;
%>

<html>
<body>
<% 
   String insert_sql ;
   String usermail, password; 
   usermail=request.getParameter("uid");  
   password=request.getParameter("pwd");  

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "xxx", "xxx");
statement = connection.createStatement();

insert_sql = "insert into user ( usermail, userpassword ) values ( '" + usermail + "' , '" + password + "')" ; 
insert_flag = statement.executeUpdate( insert_sql );

if ( insert_flag > 0 ) out.println("record inserted") ;

%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you said you figured out? would you post the solution you found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass Query parameters with your Request. In JSP you can retrieve the values by:

```
<%= request.getParameter("name") %>
```

Enjoy

Comment: I have figured it out. Thanks for your reply anyway:)

Comment: yes, you are right. But it is not that much related to what i am asked at that time as you may see i actually used the right code in asp :)